# Hive query for selecting data points in between max date and previous 30 days for each unique id

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, ambari

Data Contains unique IDs with different latitudes and longitudes on multiple timestamps.I would like to select the rows of latest 30 days of coordinates for each unique ID.Please help me on how to run the query . This date is in Hive table.unable write the sub query

[image: hi]

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date > date_add(max_date, -30);
```

Comment: thank you @gordon linoff,i have a quick question does hives tables accept the windows function through hive sql query

Comment: @akshaydirisala . . . Hive SQL supports windows functions.

Comment: running the below hive query to extract data inbetween latest date and previous 30 days of unique IDs from hive table,but unable to extract the data using the subquery inside hive sql query,please tell me what i am doing wrong.

**Select temp.x,temp.y,temp.z,temp.w
from 
 (select x,y,z,w,
             max(y) over (partition by x) as max_date
      from t1 as temp) temp  
where t1.y>date_add(max_date,-30);**      Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'column name' ',' in join source (state=42000,code=40000) @gordon

Comment: @akshaydirisala . . . Something is wrong with your query but it shouldn't be the window function.